# drop down menu not working

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Red Carpet Films</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Movies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Genres<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Action</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action1</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Adventure</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Adventure1</a></li>
```

drop down menu doesn't work properly. when I click on genre it doesn't present a list.. does nothing except has the little arrow sign indicating its a dropdown list

Comment: this markup is incomplete...please show complete markup and bootstrap version you are using!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Try to edit your post. Correct code formatting. Correct your description. There are punctuation errors.

Comment: Please submit your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can test/change it there.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the dependents for bootstrap.

THis is a JavaScript issue.  Include

- jQuery
- bootstrap.min.js

at the bottom of the HTML document.  Simple mistake made often.  Been there...done that...